# How to override the .go code of a resource argument in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

There is a 1024 character restriction set for the AWS `aws_alb_listener_rule` resource that is imposed [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/bbae8b75ab755f68ae10efd54a5abb1d1db827c5/internal/service/elbv2/listener_rule.go#L223). I need to parameterise this character limit as the message body I want to send in the response is longer than 1024 characters.

I am new to terraform, is it possible to make such alterations to the .go code somewhere and bring this through to the `aws_lb_listener_rule`  resource used in my terraform project?

Ideally I would have a resource like:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "discovery" {
  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.func.arn
    
  action {
    type = "fixed-response"
    
    fixed_response {
      content_type = "application/json"
      message_body = jsonencode(local.discovery)
      status_code  = "200",
      message_body_chr_limit = 2000,
    }
  }
    
  condition {
    path_pattern {
      values = [
        "/discovery"]
    }
  }
    
  tags = var.infra_tags
}
```

Is this possible to do? Or does it require PR to the AWS terraform project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [AWS defined limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_FixedResponseActionConfig.html), so the answer is it cannot be done:

> Length Constraints: Minimum length of 0. Maximum length of 1024.